How can one intuitively understand the dependence of the set relative to which homotopies are constructed?
In the notes I am using, homotopy is defined relative to a set. To start the discussion I present the definition:

Two functions $f,g:(X, \tau_x) \to (Y,\tau_y)$ are said to be homotopic relative to a set $\color{red}{A} \subset X$, if there exists a continous function $H:X \times [0,1] \to Y$ which satisfies the following four properties:

H is continous

$H(x,0)=f(x)$

$H(x,1) = g(x)$

$\color{red}{H(a,\lambda) = f(a) = g(a)}$



How do I understand how homotopy changes as I change $A$?
What I found so far:
Obviously, if we make $A=X$, then each function is only homotopic to itself. In the very simple case of functions between $\mathbb{R}$, we have that if we choose $A$ to be empty, then all continous functions are homotopic to each other by the homotopy given by:
$$H(x,\lambda) = f(x) + (g(x)-f(x)) \lambda$$
Which gives me a feeling that if we reduce the size of $A$ , more functions in $C(X,Y)$ are homotopic to each other.

"Obviously, if we make $A=X$, then only constant functions are homotopic to each other." Obviously this statement is false. If you take $A = X$ then the only function homotopic to a given $f$ is $f$ itself.

The first special case to think about is the case that $X = [0, 1]$ is an interval and $A = { 0, 1 }$ consists of its endpoints. Then this definition is intended to capture the notion of a homotopy between two paths whose starting and ending points are fixed. The general definition is a large generalization of this.
